# How to create copy of full schema on same database in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration

I want to create full copy of the schema on the same database. What is the best technique to do that?

I have few ideas in mind:

1. Datapump Over Db link
2. IMPDP on network link
3. EXPDP and then IMPDP.

What would be the advantages and/or drawbacks of each technique?

Answer (score 28):

You don't need a fancy network link or anything just the expdp/impdp commands.
First export the schema that you want:

```
expdp fromUser/fromPword schemas=sourceSchema directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=explog.txt
```

Tip: make sure that that user has the ability to write to DUMPDIR or whatever it is you call it

Then reimport the schema using the `remap_schema` parameter:

```
impdp toUser/toPword directory=DUMPDIR dumpfile=dump.dmp logfile=implog.txt remap_schema=fromUser:toUser
```

If you really want to use the network_link parameter (so you don't create a dumpfile for some reason) then I recommend reading [this](http://www.javaroots.com/2013/10/expdp-impdp-remote-oracle-db-example.html) or [this](http://www.acehints.com/2011/07/data-pump-impdp-expdp-networklink.html).
Great info on your question is found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/exporting-schema-data-tables-permisions-into-another-schema-on-same-database) also.

Comment: That worked for me, although I had some struggle with permissions that I eventually resolved by running the commands with a sysdba login - the schemas / remap_schema parameters still tell what to export/import. The directory param can be omitted when the default is ok for you, see http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump#Create_database_directories.

Comment: @Matthias Do not EXP/IMP as SYS. :)

Comment: In the above example where you run the impdp command is it assumed that you have already created the new 'toUser' schema? Or will the command take care of that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[Copy schema into same database](https://web.archive.org/web/20150105082543/http://learnwithme11g.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/copy-schema-into-same-database-with-impdp/)

I tested and it worked. but you have to create a public link like mentioned in the comments.

If you create a .par file which remaps your tablespaces you can reuse it. With some search replace of course.

O and don't forget to put the transaform in the .par file:

```
TRANSFORM=oid:n
```

Otherwise you might get errors.

Comment: Interesting but that solution terrifies me

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

The steps I did to copy schema's content from schema `user_a` to schema `user_b` in Oracle:
DBMS is located inside an Oracle Linux Server container.

let's assume the schemas are defined like that:

```
create user user_a identified by user_a_pass default tablespace tablespace_a;
grant
    create materialized view,
    create procedure,
    create sequence,
    create session,
    create table,
    create type,
    create trigger,
    create view to user_a;

create user user_b identified by user_b_pass default tablespace tablespace_a;
grant
    create materialized view,
    create procedure,
    create sequence,
    create session,
    create table,
    create type,
    create trigger,
    create view to user_b;
```

The important point here: the schemas have access to the same tablespace and have create session privilege.

in order to copy, data schemas' directory are required:
check granted directory:

```
select tp.grantee, tp.table_name from all_tab_privs tp where tp.privilege = 'WRITE' and tp.type = 'DIRECTORY';
```

check that the directory's path phisically exists and a group `dba` has an access to that.

if directory is not assigned to the schema user, do that:

```
create or replace directory user_dir as '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/user_dir_name';
grant read, write on directory user_dir to user_a;
grant read, write on directory user_dir to user_b;
```

run export:

```
expdp user_a/user_a_pass@host/database schemas=user_a directory=user_dir dumpfile=user_a.dmp logfile=schema_exp.log
```

run import:

```
impdp user_b/user_b_pass@host/database directory=user_dir dumpfile=user_a.dmp logfile=schema_imp.log remap_schema=user_a:user_b
```